# Linear search on two 1D arrays

Tags: python

I want to search one array and return a value from another. Here is what I have right now. Not sure how to get this to work.

```html
CustNumber=str(raw_input("Please enter the Customer's Number:"))

If CustNumber in Customers:
    print ("Customer Number: " +str(Customers[i])+"Name:"+(str(Names[i])))

else:
           print ("not found")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `i` is undefined here. You have to define it first with the index of the element you are looking for.

```
if CustNumber in Customers:
    i = Customers.index(CustNumber)
    print ("Customer Number: " +str(Customers[i])+"Name:"+(str(Names[i])))
else:
    print ("not found")
```

You can also use error handling to avoid the if statement:

```
try:
    i = Customers.index(CustNumber)
    print ("Customer Number: " +str(Customers[i])+"Name:"+(str(Names[i])))
except ValueError:
    print ("not found")
```

Comment: I wasn't sure how to declare the I variable, It works as intended. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. You can accept the answer to show that the answer helped you to future readers.